# How do i install a package I downloaded manually into visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I dont do this very often so excuse me the question is so basic.

I found an example of parallax effect online I wanted to test.
called paroller.js
So the site offered for me to download their package and I did, its now on my desktop.

And now I have no idea how to include this in my solution, I went to nuget package manager to search for it, but cannot find it.

Link to where i got it from: https://tgomilar.github.io/paroller.js/

I tried using the nuget package manager, and I googled a million different ways to install packages into solutions and all want me to use the package manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that nuget does is to download the files build them ( if needed) and add the required references. So, you apparently want to add a js lib. You should look for the dist folder in the package that you want and import it in your page.

Note if there is not dist folder you may need to build the package which is not that simple.

Comment: Well, you can import it but it won't do any difference, you should add the script in the page where you need it e.i. `<script src="[your path]" language="JavaScript" />` or I think that if you add it to your project you can just drag it over your page.

Comment: thx. Ive been going at it all wrong thinking it was a package.
I got the js. files from the dist folder and add them to project and reference them, so Im hoping Im on the right track now